# remove the stretchy top animation on .onDelete in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have this code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var items = [Int]()
    @State private var value  = 1
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(items, id: \.self) {
                    Text("\($0)")
                }
                .onDelete(perform: DeleteRow)
            }
            
            Button("Add Number") {
                self.items.append(self.value)
                self.value += 1
            }
        }
    }
    func DeleteRow(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()) {
            items.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
        }
    }
    
}
```

Want i want to do is to remove the stretchy top animation line when deleting an item . I could not find any solution online. I attached a pic . The red line attached to the animation is what i want to remove.I delete item 9 in this example.[image]